# RoR: Multilevel nested save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship, nested-attributes

In Ruby on rails I try to save data in multiple table with lots of relations.

My models looks:

**evid.rb:**

```
class Evid < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :kod, :nazov, :okruh_id, :bank_ucets_attributes, :poc_stavs_attributes
    #attr_accessible :ciselny_rads_attributes

    has_many :ciselny_rads
    has_many :bank_ucets, :foreign_key => :evidencia_id
    has_many :poc_stavs, :foreign_key => :evidencia_id

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :poc_stavs, :allow_destroy => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bank_ucets, :allow_destroy => true
    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :ciselny_rads, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**bank_ucet.rb**

```
class BankUcet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ciselny_rad_id, :evidencia_id
  attr_accessible :ciselny_rad_attributes

  belongs_to :ciselny_rad
  belongs_to :evid, :foreign_key => "evidencia_id"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ciselny_rad, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

**ciselny_rad.rb**

```
class CiselnyRad < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :evidencia_id, :kod, :nazov, :ciselny_rad_cislos_attributes

    belongs_to :evid, :foreign_key => "evidencia_id"
    has_many :ciselny_rad_cislos, :dependent => :delete_all

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ciselny_rad_cislos, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**poc_stav.rb**

```
class PocStav < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :evidencia_id, :hosp_roky_id, :poc_stav

    belongs_to :evid, :foreign_key => :evidencia_id
end
```

And I am trying to save data

```
@bank_ucet = Evid.create(data)

data={
    "kod": "XX",
    "nazov": "XxxXxUxXxxX",
    "okruh_id": 5,
    "bank_ucets_attributes": [
        {
            "cis_banka_id": 1,
            "cislo_uctu": 999999,
            "cis_mena_id": 1,
            "ciselny_rad_attributes": {
                "kod": "XX",
                "nazov": "XxxXxUxXxxX"
            }
        }
    ],
    "poc_stavs_attributes": [
        {
            "hosp_roky_id": null,
            "poc_stav": 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything works great, but the only problem is, that evidencia_id in table ciselny_rad is filled with null, not the new created evid.

Can you help me please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
has_many :bank_ucets, :foreign_key => :evidencia_id, :inverse_of => :evid
```

in your `Evid` class and:

```
belongs_to :evid, :foreign_key => "evidencia_id", :inverse_of => :bank_ucets
```

in your `BankUcet` class.

(Edit) Reasoning: in my experience of using nested attributes, throwing `inverse_of` in and around the place usually sorts out any problems..